# How to prevent going back after the user pressed the GoBack hardware button?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, navigation, windows-phone-7.1, windows-phone-8.1

I have a page that runs an asynchronous operation.

Wnen the user press the H/W back button on the phone, I would like the application to be asked the user if he "really" wants to exit that page? If the answer is YES than GoBack but if the answer is NO than to stay on the same page.

How can I do that?

```
MessageBoxResult result = MessageBox.Show("Do you really want to leave this page?", "", MessageBoxButton.OKCancel);

    if ( result == MessageBoxResult.OK )
        {
        // .... Go Back
        }
    else
        {
        // .... Stay on the same page
        }
```

Thx!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Override the backkeypress event

```
protected override void OnBackKeyPress(CancelEventArgs e)
{
    if(MessageBox.Show("Are you sure you want to exit?","Exit?", 
                            MessageBoxButton.OKCancel) != MessageBoxResult.OK)
    {
        e.Cancel = true; 

    }
}
```